# Pinterest OAuth API not redirecting?

Tags: ios, api, authentication, oauth, pinterest

I've been using the Pinterest REST API in an iOS app.  I use an embedded UIWebView and start the auth process by loading this URL (client_id and redirect_uri values edited):

```
https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/
?client_id=1234567890
&scope=read_public,read_relationships
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%mysite.com%2Foauth%2Fpinterest
&state=E95D914D-78B5-4E16-B8AA-8BD0774CC347
&response_type=code
```

This has worked fine until recently.  Now, the Pinterest login page is displayed, but after logging in, I'm being redirected to https://www.pinterest.com, not my redirect_uri.  I've double-checked that the URI matches in my app configuration on https://developers.pinterest.com.

I've also tried it using [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw), with the same result.

It's as if the OAuth context is being ignored, and it's just being treated as a normal web login.  Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, but it is functioning correctly with a desktop User-Agent.

Comment: Thanks.  Same behavior with https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/ -- works on desktop Safari, doesn't work on mobile Safari.  I tweeted @PinterestEng, no reply yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been fixed at the server end.